# How to get what's inside a Javascript <script> from a webpage using Selenium on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I want to get some data from the "BATTLE_SERVER_DATA" in this piece of code off a webpage.

```
<hovercard-details></hovercard-details><script charset="utf-8" id="BATTLE_SERVER_DATA">
var BATTLE_TEXTS = $j.extend({}, {"consume_food":"Consume Food","cosume_energy_bar_text":"Consume Energy Bar","cosume_winter_treat_text":"Consume Ice Creams","buy_health_kit":"Get more energy","event_boss_error_1":"Nice try, but you cannot kill your enemies with the Silver Stake!","event_boss_error_2":"You must use the Silver Stake to defeat Dracula!","won_zone":"won the previous battle","division":"Division","the_airforce":"The Airforce","of":"of","won_division":"won this battle","won_battle":"won this campaign","yourHealth":"Your Energy:","opponentHealth":"Opponent Energy:","defenderHero":"Our battle hero","attackerHero":"Enemy Battle Hero","processing_battle":"Processing battle results","military_rank":"Military rank:","get_ready":"get ready","duel":"duel","fight":"Fight","ticket_info_msg":"No travelling costs will be deducted, instead a Q%%1%% ticket will be used.","notEnoughMoney":"You don't have enough citizenship currency (%%1%%).","fightAgainstBrothersTitle":"","fightAgainstBrothersBody":""}),
    SERVER_DATA = $j.extend(SERVER_DATA, {"initialLoad":true,"battleId":138240,"countryId":165,"mySideCountryId":165,"invaderId":165,"defenderId":1,"leftBattleId":1,"rightBattleId":165,"realInvaderId":165,"realDefenderId":1,"zoneId":12,"currentRoundNumber":12,"battleFinished":0,"isResistance":true,"isCivilWar":false,"mustInvert":false,"spectatorOnly":true,"onAirforceBattlefield":true,"battleZoneSituation":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"11":0},"points":{"defender":0,"attacker":50},"battle_critical_at":new Date('Wed, 08 Aug 2018 17:30:02 -0700'),"battle_start_at":new Date('Wed, 08 Aug 2018 15:30:02 -0700'),"server_time":new Date('Wed, 08 Aug 2018 15:35:31 -0700'),"zoneElapsedTime":"0:5:29","battle_close_to_finish":0,"citizenId":7662082,"militaryUnitId":162,"regimentId":316,"division":11,"currentDivision":11,"weaponSkinId":0,"opponentSkinId":0,"canSwitchDivisions":true,"health":595,"level":56,"currentWeaponId":-1,"hasBazookaAmmo":-1,"showTravelPopup":true,"fightAgainstBrothers":false,"travelRequired":true,"countries":{"167":"Albania","27":"Argentina","169":"Armenia","50":"Australia","33":"Austria","83":"Belarus","32":"Belgium","76":"Bolivia","69":"Bosnia-Herzegovina","9":"Brazil","42":"Bulgaria","23":"Canada","64":"Chile","14":"China","78":"Colombia","63":"Croatia","171":"Cuba","82":"Cyprus","34":"Czech-Republic","55":"Denmark","165":"Egypt","70":"Estonia","39":"Finland","11":"France","168":"Georgia","12":"Germany","44":"Greece","13":"Hungary","48":"India","49":"Indonesia","56":"Iran","54":"Ireland","58":"Israel","10":"Italy","45":"Japan","71":"Latvia","72":"Lithuania","66":"Malaysia","26":"Mexico","80":"Montenegro","31":"Netherlands","84":"New-Zealand","170":"Nigeria","73":"North-Korea","37":"Norway","57":"Pakistan","75":"Paraguay","77":"Peru","67":"Philippines","35":"Poland","53":"Portugal","81":"Republic-of-China-Taiwan","79":"Republic-of-Macedonia-FYROM","52":"Republic-of-Moldova","1":"Romania","41":"Russia","164":"Saudi-Arabia","65":"Serbia","68":"Singapore","36":"Slovakia","61":"Slovenia","51":"South-Africa","47":"South-Korea","15":"Spain","38":"Sweden","30":"Switzerland","59":"Thailand","43":"Turkey","40":"Ukraine","166":"United-Arab-Emirates","29":"United-Kingdom","74":"Uruguay","24":"USA","28":"Venezuela"},"regionsInvolved":[],"tickets":[],"rocket_damage":750000,"bomb_damage":5000000,"specialWeapons":[],"canUseCatchupBooster":true,"regimentBoosters":[],"regimentBooster":false,"eventDamageBoosters":[],"eventDamageBooster":false,"boosters":{"active":[],"inactive":{"speedBoosters":{"100_speedBoosters_3_600":{"name":"x9 Damage Accelerator","id":"100_speedBoosters_3_600","industryId":100,"quality":3,"amount":1,"activable":1,"deactivable":0,"activableFromInventory":1,"activableFromBattlefield":1,"activationData":{"tooltip":"x9 Damage Accelerator","url":"/en/military/fight-activateBooster","params":{"type":"speed","quality":3,"duration":600}},"active":0,"icon":0,"tooltip":"x9 Damage Accelerator for 10 minutes","token":"","attributes":{"damageAcceleration":{"id":"damageAcceleration","name":"Hit 9 times faster","type":"use","value":"x9"},"duration":{"id":"duration","name":"Duration","type":"minutes","value":600}},"isRaw":0,"isPartial":0,"type":"speedBoosters","duration":600,"isBooster":1,"isPackBooster":0,"canActivateBooster":1},"100_speedBoosters_2_600":{"name":"x5 Damage Accelerator","id":"100_speedBoosters_2_600","industryId":100,"quality":2,"amount":106,"activable":1,"deactivable":0,"activableFromInventory":1,"activableFromBattlefield":1,"activationData":{"tooltip":"x5 Damage Accelerator","url":"/en/military/fight-activateBooster","params":{"type":"speed","quality":2,"duration":600}},"active":0,"icon":0,"tooltip":"x5 Damage Accelerator for 10 minutes","token":"","attributes":{"damageAcceleration":{"id":"damageAcceleration","name":"Hit 5 times faster","type":"use","value":"x5"},"duration":{"id":"duration","name":"Duration","type":"minutes","value":600}},"isRaw":0,"isPartial":0,"type":"speedBoosters","duration":600,"isBooster":1,"isPackBooster":0,"canActivateBooster":1},"100_speedBoosters_1_300":{"name":"x2 Damage Accelerator","id":"100_speedBoosters_1_300","industryId":100,"quality":1,"amount":176,"activable":1,"deactivable":0,"activableFromInventory":1,"activableFromBattlefield":1,"activationData":{"tooltip":"x2 Damage Accelerator","url":"/en/military/fight-activateBooster","params":{"type":"speed","quality":1,"duration":300}},"active":0,"icon":0,"tooltip":"x2 Damage Accelerator for 5 minutes","token":"","attributes":{"damageAcceleration":{"id":"damageAcceleration","name":"Hit 2 times faster","type":"use","value":"x2"},"duration":{"id":"duration","name":"Duration","type":"minutes","value":300}},"isRaw":0,"isPartial":0,"type":"speedBoosters","duration":300,"isBooster":1,"isPackBooster":0,"canActivateBooster":1}},"prestigePointsBoosters":{"100_prestigePointsBoosters_1_301":{"name":"+1 Prestige Points Booster","id":"100_prestigePointsBoosters_1_301","industryId":100,"quality":1,"amount":2,"activable":1,"deactivable":0,"activableFromInventory":1,"activableFromBattlefield":1,"activationData":{"tooltip":"Your Prestige Points Booster availability","url":"/en/military/fight-activateBooster","params":{"type":"prestige_points","quality":1,"duration":301}},"active":0,"icon":0,"tooltip":"Increase your prestige by 1 for 5.0166666666667 minutes","token":"","attributes":{"prestigeBoost":{"id":"prestigeBoost","name":"+1 Prestige Points","type":"use","value":1},"duration":{"id":"duration","name":"Duration","type":"minutes","value":301}},"isRaw":0,"isPartial":0,"type":"prestigePointsBoosters","duration":301,"isBooster":1,"isPackBooster":0,"canActivateBooster":1}}},"canUseCatchupBooster":true,"events":[]},"has_jid":1,"pvpKillCount":0,"pvpShowLock":false,"tutorial":0,"mission1Completed":true,"mission2Completed":true,"mission3Completed":true,"hasActiveObjective":false,"hasDestroyedObjective":false,"canDeployObjective":false,"aoe_effects":[],"battle_effects":{"valentinesDay":{"is_active":0}},"aoeMyDivision":true,"aoeOtherDivisionData":[],"fightersData":[],"historyStats":[],"culture":"en","csrfToken":"9f030d06b52292457b7a1a1b1907d043","isLoggedIn":true,"ERPK_ECONOMY_HOST":"economy.erepublik.com","ERPK_MAIN_HOST":"www.erepublik.com","extras":"Ice Creams","texts":{"consume_food":"Consume Food","cosume_energy_bar_text":"Consume Energy Bar","cosume_winter_treat_text":"Consume Ice Creams","buy_health_kit":"Get more energy","event_boss_error_1":"Nice try, but you cannot kill your enemies with the Silver Stake!","event_boss_error_2":"You must use the Silver Stake to defeat Dracula!","won_zone":"won the previous battle","division":"Division","the_airforce":"The Airforce","of":"of","won_division":"won this battle","won_battle":"won this campaign","yourHealth":"Your Energy:","opponentHealth":"Opponent Energy:","defenderHero":"Our battle hero","attackerHero":"Enemy Battle Hero","processing_battle":"Processing battle results","military_rank":"Military rank:","get_ready":"get ready","duel":"duel","fight":"Fight","ticket_info_msg":"No travelling costs will be deducted, instead a Q%%1%% ticket will be used.","notEnoughMoney":"You don't have enough citizenship currency (%%1%%).","fightAgainstBrothersTitle":"","fightAgainstBrothersBody":""}}),
    regionsInvolved = [],
    currentWeaponId = -1,
    hasBazookaAmmo = -1,
    tickets = [],
    ticket_info_msg = BATTLE_TEXTS['ticket_info_msg'],
    notEnoughMoney = BATTLE_TEXTS['notEnoughMoney'],
    erepublik = erepublik || {},
    currentDivision = SERVER_DATA.onAirforceBattlefield ? 11 : SERVER_DATA.division,
    allDivisions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 11];
```

The methodology I've been trying is the following:

```
def checkbattle():
    browser.get(BattleLink)
    checkBattleData = browser.execute_script('return BATTLE_SERVER_DATA;')
    print(checkBattleData)
```

It doesn't work as I need it to and returns

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="fb78e0c364bfe0b31fb94aa701298789", element="0.7451343445847121-1")>
```

My main goal is to retrieve the data present in there, for example I might like to find whether or not "initialLoad" in SERVER_DATA inside BATTLE_SERVER_DATA is true or not. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify things... `browser.execute_script()` is the way you can execute Javascript code through Selenium. So the `return BATTLE_SERVER_DATA;` code you are executing is basically returning the value of a variable, `BATTLE_SERVER_DATA`, which from the HTML you've included is null/empty. The only reference I see to `BATTLE_SERVER_DATA` in the HTML you provided is that it's the ID of a `SCRIPT` tag so from that I'm assuming you want to get the code/script contained inside of that `SCRIPT` tag. If that's what you are trying to do, you can use Selenium to get the tag and then pull the innerHTML of that element to get the text/script inside.

```
def checkbattle():
    browser.get(BattleLink)
    checkBattleData = browser.find_element_by_id('BATTLE_SERVER_DATA').get_attribute('innerHTML')
    print(checkBattleData)
```

From there you can parse out the pieces that you want.